# Quel nom vient de la même racine que gluant ?

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie, synonymes

Je cherche un mot à insérer dans la seconde phrase afin qu'elle ait le même sens que la première.

> Cette chose est très gluante.

et

> Cette chose a beaucoup de [gluantitude, gluantisme, gluantuosité, gluation].

Je doute que mes essais aient d'autres vertus que celle de vous faire rire.

Comment: Il y aurait bien la glu, mais dans le contexte ça ne colle pas.

Comment: Alors là chapeau ! Je suis scotché par ta répartie !

Comment: Intuitivement, j'aurais pensé à *viscosité* car je n'ai jamais entendu parler des mots évoqués par Cédric Julien.

Comment: Viscosité a bien la même signification que le mot que je cherchais, mais il vient de la même racine que « visqueux », ce qui ne répond pas à ma question. Merci quand-même !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gluance) suggère **gluance**, également confirmé par le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gluance).

> L'horrible hiver, la fange, la gluance des choses

Et je viens de découvrir le verbe gluer. :

> Un roman, on ne peut pas le relire, les mots gluent aux yeux
>   (Beauvoir, Mandarins,1954, p. 245)

Comment: Ah ben voilà, merci tout plein !